# Google Fonts weights not rendering properly

Tags: css, fonts, google-font-api

Take a look here: https://jsfiddle.net/n26a7gtp/

300 and 400 are exactly the same, and 600, 700, and 800 are exactly the same. On the [Google Fonts page](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Open+Sans) you can see the weights look drastically different.

I'm trying to get 800 and noticed it looked a little thin, so I imported all of the weights to compare them and noticed the 800 was just the 600. I'm importing the font through the URL `https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700,800`.

What is that Google Fonts page doing that I'm not?

Comment: The fiddle isn't loading the font. That's a serif font, not sans-serif (open sans). I added it as a link tag https://jsfiddle.net/n26a7gtp/1/

Comment: @MichaelCoker Maybe the Open Sans I have installed on my computer is interfering with it in some way? I tried it on another device and it was doing the same thing though. I tried it with [Roboto](https://jsfiddle.net/eLgqxav6/) (a font I do not have installed) and it worked as it should. Do the Open Sans weights look different from each other on your device? [This](http://i.imgur.com/4cuSXnV.png) is how they look on my end.

Comment: they look different to me http://i.imgur.com/0k4J3xk.png

Comment: @MichaelCoker I guess the solution to this is going to be more complicated than I would have liked. Thanks for your help anyway.